# Session Error on project transfer to Macbook

Tags: macos, codeigniter, session, xampp

I was recently working on a project using Codeigniter and was developing on a local server using XAMPP.

The laptop I was using was an HP laptop running Windows 10. I decided to buy a Macbook Pro running macOS High Sierra v.10.13.6 as a replacement for my old and worn out HP laptop.

After installing needed tools for development, I copied my project folder and transferred it to my new Macbook Pro. Turned on the servers, imported the databases and now I checked to see if the project is running. But going to the project on the browser shows only this:

[image]

I'm very new to macOS and still figuring things out. The installation went well and everything went well and I did not touched anything. What's the meaning of these errors?

Comment: What version of CI are you using? It seems to me that the place codeigniter is trying to save the session has incorrect file/folder permissions.

Comment: CI3 @marcogmonteiro

Answer (score 0):

It's seem you don't have permission to write a folder. This is confusing for who new to Unix OS (Linux/Mac).

The simple way to solve this problem is changing the Session directory.

1. Open `application/config/config.php`
2. Change `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();`

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Try to set session directory manually, and then set the directory owner to your server owner. Default for Apache is `_www`.